# How to prevent re-ordering of divs on page reload with createElement and appendChild?

Tags: javascript

I have the following array:

`const users = ['freecodecamp', 'esl_sc2', 'jhovgaard'];`

And I'm dynamically creating a `<div>` with `document.createElement();` for each array item and appending to the DOM with `appendChild();`. For instance,

**HTML**

```
<div id='twitchBox'>
  <!-- <div>s for array items will go here -->
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function initialize() {
  const users = ['freecodecamp', 'esl_sc2', 'jhovgaard'];
  let channelUrl = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i += 1) {
    channelUrl = `https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/channels/${users[i]}`;
    ajaxRequest(channelUrl);
  }
}

// called by ajaxRequest
function showChannelLogoAndName(data) {
  // extracts json data that'll be used in app
  const json = JSON.parse(data);
  const userName = json.name;
  const logoSrc = json.logo;

  // creates elements for displaying channel details
  const twitchBox = document.getElementById('twitchBox');
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  const logo = document.createElement('img');
  const spanForUserName = document.createElement('span');
  const anchor = document.createElement('a');

  // functions called set up channel divs with logo and link
  createLogo(logo, logoSrc, displayName);
  createHyperLinkedUserName(anchor, spanForUserName, displayName);

  // adds channel details to streamer container
  div.setAttribute('id', userName);
  div.setAttribute('class', 'streamers');
  div.appendChild(logo);
  div.appendChild(spanForUserName);

  twitchBox.appendChild(div);
}
```

Because the array is `const users = ['freecodecamp', 'esl_sc2', 'jhovgaard'];`, I expect:

- `freecodecamp` to be appear first in the browser
- `esl_sc2` to be second
- and `jhovgaard` to be third

**However, after several page reloads, the ordering is shuffled and random.**

You can see the behavior in a gif [here](https://media.giphy.com/media/26gsjgld7JbCrhY9W/source.gif).

Why is this so? Why doesn't the order of the `<div>`s *always* match the order of the array items?

Comment: I take that `showChannelLogoAndName` is called by `ajaxrequest` on success ?

Comment: Yes, yes exactly.

Comment: What does the A in AJAX stand for?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much of issue with your code. The calls are async. This is randomness that you mention.

If you really want to go in a line call the `function` itself upon `success` or `always` to continue even on error

The sample below highlights what/how you should update your `ajaxRequest` function

```js
var index = 0;

function CallMe(id) {
  var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
  $.ajax({
    url: root + '/users?id=' + id,
    method: 'GET',
    cache: false
  }).success(function(data) {
    $('pre').append(JSON.stringify(data[0], null, '\t'));
    index++; //increment always
    if (users[index] != undefined) {
      //call with the next item
      CallMe(users[index]);
    }
  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    console.log(jqXHR);
  });
}
const users = [1, 2, 302125, 3, 10291, 4, 5]; //your users
CallMe(users[index]); //initial call for the first element
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<pre>
  
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question here is essentially: *How do async calls work?*

And this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&t=149s) by Philip Roberts **What the heck is the event loop anyway?** brilliantly explains how asynchronous calls work.

He also built a tool called [Loupe](http://latentflip.com/loupe/) that lets you **visualize** the JavaScript runtime *at* runtime so you can understand what's going on with your async calls behind the scenes.